# Windows 2012 Server R2 in the cloud. Move to another cloud provider

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cloud

We have a Windows Server machine in the cloud. The service of our cloud provider is terrible, so we want to move to another one.

My question: is there any way we can change the hosting provider without having to reinstall the machine?

We have SQL Server with some databases, IIS Web Apps, and some ERP software. I would like to take an image of the configuration and software installed over this Windows Server and take it to another one!

Comment: `We have a Windows Server machine in the cloud.` - Wow, talk about a vague and meaningless statement. If you'd like quality answers you'll need to improve the quality of your question. You've provided us almost no useful details whatsoever. Where exactly "in the cloud" is the server? Is it virtual or physical?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this is the not an option since, most hosting provider does not provide the backup/restore of your VPS image from another provider. Moreover, both the provider should be using same virtulization technology. SO that will be difficult to find such provider who can do this for you as you can't do this at your end.